# How to split a serverless configuration file?

Tags: serverless, serverless-framework

I'm trying to split my serverless configuration file `serverless.yml` into multiple files using the `${file(...)}` syntax. I have a provider file `config/serverless/provider.yml` with the following content:

```
provider:
  name: ...
  ...
```

And in my `serverless.yml` I've used it in the following way:

```
provider: ${file(config/serverless/provider.yml):provider}
```

However, when I run `serverless deploy`, I get the following error:

```
Cannot resolve serverless.yml: Variables resolution errored with:
  - Cannot resolve variable at "provider": Value not found at "file"
```

Please help me to understand **how to properly include other files in my serverless configuration**.

---

NOTE: I've also tried with this config without success

*provider.yml*

```
name: ...
...
```

*serverless.yml*

```
...
resources:
  - ${file(config/serverless/provider.yml)}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Cannot resolve serverless.yml: Variables resolution errored with:
  - Cannot resolve variable at "provider": Value not found at "file"
```

The error is not finding a value at "file" double check the file path.

Make sure the path you are using in `${file(<this-path-here>):provider}`

It is pointing to the correct file.

The following works:

- File: `serverless.yml`

```yaml
service: serverless-framework-include-files
frameworkVersion: "3"

provider: ${file(config/provider.yml):provider}

functions:
  function1:
    handler: index.handler
```

- File: `config/provider.yml`

```yaml
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs18.x
```

---

Alternatively, you can remove the `:provider` from the `${file(...):provider}`:

The following works:

- File: `serverless2.yml`

```yaml
service: serverless-framework-include-files
frameworkVersion: "3"

provider: ${file(config/provider2.yml)}

functions:
  function1:
    handler: index.handler
```

- File: `config/provider2.yml`

```yaml
name: aws
runtime: nodejs18.x
```

---

For `resources:`, the same applies.

This works:

- File: `serverless.yml`

```yaml
resources:
 - ${file(resources/s3-bucket.yml)}
 - ${file(resources/dynamodb-table.yml)}
```

- File: `resources/s3-bucket.yml`

```yaml
Resources:
  MyBucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    Properties:
      BucketName: my-bucket
      AccessControl: PublicRead
      WebsiteConfiguration:
        IndexDocument: index.html
        ErrorDocument: error.html
```

Alternatively, you can do:

- File `serverless2.yml`

```yaml
resources:
  Resources:
    MyBucket: ${file(resources/s3-bucket2.yml)}
    MyTable: ${file(resources/dynamodb-table2.yml)}
```

- File `resources/dynamodb-table2.yml`

```yaml
Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
Properties:
  TableName: ${self:service}
  AttributeDefinitions:
    - AttributeName: id
      AttributeType: S
  KeySchema:
    - AttributeName: id
      KeyType: HASH
  ProvisionedThroughput:
    ReadCapacityUnits: 1
    WriteCapacityUnits: 1
```

---

You can check the GitHub code for a working example:

- https://github.com/oieduardorabelo/serverless-framework-include-files

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer, but I don't get it. Your first example isn't exactly the same as mine?

Comment: You are correct @Guglie. I would suggest double-checking the file path and file contents in your folder structure. You can clone the GitHub example and see if it works for you.

Comment: Yes, I already spotted a classic typo in the paths, nice answer though